# Excel VBA selecting worksheets and ranges in one of my sub routines not working

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getting the error, "Select Method of Range Class Failed" and unexpected results from Rows("2:2").Insert

Code below

```
Worksheets("Sheet3").Select

Rows("2:2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove    

Range("D4").Select
```

First the new row is added to Sheet 1 not sheet 3 and then Range cannot be selected 1004 error. I have used this exact script to select other worksheets and ranges without an issue. I can provide the full file and code for anyone who can help

Comment: See [Worksheet .Name, .Index or .CodeName](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/2240/excel-vba-tips-and-tricks/11272/worksheet-name-index-or-codename).

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the use of `.Select`. You may want to see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Also ensure that your worksheet is unprotected.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Worksheets("Sheet3").Rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Comment: I am using .select so that I have a permanent starting point. Later in the code I utilize a For Next loop                                                                      For i = 1 To myarraycount
    
    ActiveCell.Value = BidItemsName(i)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = BidItems(i)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = BidItemQuant(i)
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
    
    Next i

Comment: And that is exactly what you must ignore. Please re-read the link that I have given you :)

Answer (score 0):

The code below works, define the Sheet, and not using `Select` (the first time):

```
Dim sht3 As Worksheet

Set sht3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

sht3.Rows("2:2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
sht3.Range("D4").Select
```

Comment: When I use the code I provided in a different Sub() there is no issues, it only occurs in one of my segments.

Comment: @BKruk then you need to provide the rest of your code, so we can see where and why are you getting this error

Answer (score 0):

When you are using select you'll always ensure that the particular sheet is active. If not activate it using activate property. Below is the code that does the work

```
Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate

Worksheets("Sheet3").Select

Rows("2:2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Range("D4").Select
```

Comment: I was able to avoid the error by creating another Sub() and adding this code: 'code'                                                                                       Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate 
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Select
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, copyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
    
    Range("E2").Select